# Regexp find ascends and diacritics

Tags: java, regex

How to find in JAVA with regexp that the string contains characters such as ľščťžýáí, that are not from US alphabet, (abcde...XYZ)? I tried [^a-z], p{L}, without success. F.i  I would like to refuse the passwords that contains such characters as umlaut, ' ˇ ´, etc... I dont want to list all the characters manually cause it can be huge number so I would prefer to list just the characters allowed(a-Z) . Thanks

- password123 : valid
- päaasword123 : invalid
- Passwörd9 : invalid

  UPDATE:
  I need to check if the password follow those rules:

  - 8 characters long,
  - at least 1 small letter
  - at least 1 Capital letter
  - at least 2 digits
  - at least 1 of the special characters:  !"#$%&‘()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^{|}~_

I use this regexp and positive lookahead, but it seems not working correctly with the umlauts, diacritics and so on.

```
       private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("" +   // Positive Lookahead
            "(?=(.*\\d){2})" +   // at least 2 numbers
            "(?=.*[a-z])" +    // small letters
            "(?=.*[A-Z])" +    // capital letters
            "(?=.*[@$!%*?&#()+,-.:;<=>~^{|}_\\u0027 \\u005B \\u005D \\u0022 \\u002F \\u005C])" +  // special characters and [ ] " / \
            "[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*?&#()+,-.:;<=>~^{|}_\\u0027 \\u005B \\u005B \\u0022 \\u002F \\u005C]" +  // list of all allowed values
            "{8,}");
```

- a!@asdf1Q5*!     // valid
- Password99%          // valid
- Password99<       // valid
- !P!@ssssswoard12345@   // valid
- PassÖwordS12!   // invalid
- PassäwordS12!   // invalid

Answer (score 2):

If you want only letters from the *Latin* alphabet and digits, you could use:

```
"[A-Za-z0-9]"
```

(assuming you want both cases)

@Mena's suggestion is more compact, but this is a bit more explicit, and doesn't leave you wondering which characters are in that class.

---

**Update for additional criteria**:

It is easiest to break down your criteria and check them separately:

```
// Check for minimum length.
if (password.length() < 8) {
  return false;
}
// Check for at least one lower case letter.
if (!Pattern.compile("[a-z]").find(password)) {
  return false;
}
// Check for at least one upper case letter.
if (!Pattern.compile("[A-Z]").find(password)) {
  return false;
}
// etc, for other requirements.
```

Attempting to write a regular expression to match all of these criteria at the same time will be hard and very difficult to change in the future.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the answer. The problem is, that I need to check also other criterias and somehow I am not able to deal with that separatelly (1 expression for 1 criteria). Please see my update.

Comment: @troger19 Updated for your additional criteria.

Comment: Andy, with this approach you will just check if the password fulfill the criteria, but you will not check if all the characters are allowed, f.i. ä, Ö

Comment: @troger please extend the code yourself. You can do this by adding the check from my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\\p{Alnum}`.

It will match alpha-numerics, but not non-ASCII characters, nor symbols, nor punctuation, etc.

**Example**

```
String[] test = {
    "password123", // valid
    "päaasword123", // invalid
    "Passwörd9", // : invalid
};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alnum}+");
for (String s: test) {
    // matching against whole input here
    System.out.println(p.matcher(s).matches());
}
```

**Output**

```
true
false
false
```

Comment: Hi Mena, thanks for the answer. The problem is, that I need to check also other criterias.  Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, checking for each constraint separatelly and at the end **exclude** the unknown characters:

```
      public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
         private static final Pattern PATTERN1 = Pattern.compile("[0-9]?[0-9]?(\\.[0-9][0-9]?)?"); // at least 2 digits
         private static final Pattern PATTERN2 = Pattern.compile("[a-z]"); //lower case
         private static final Pattern PATTERN3 = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]"); // upper case
         private static final Pattern PATTERN4 = Pattern.compile("[@$!%*?&#()+,-.:;<=>~^{|}_\\u0027 \\u005B ]"); // special Matcher regMatcher1 = PATTERN1.matcher(value);
        Matcher regMatcher2 = PATTERN2.matcher(value);
        Matcher regMatcher3 = PATTERN3.matcher(value);
        Matcher regMatcher4 = PATTERN4.matcher(value);

        // Check for minimum length.
        if (value.length() < 8) {
            return false;
        }
        // at least 2 digits
        if (!regMatcher1.find()) {
            return false;
        }
        // Check for at least one lower case letter.
        if (!regMatcher2.find()) {
            return false;
        }
        // Check for at least one upper case letter.
        if (!regMatcher3.find()) {
            return false;
        }
        // at least 1 special character
        if (!regMatcher4.find()) {
            return false;
        }
        // doesn't contain anything besides the letters, digits and special characters
        if (!value.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9!\"#$%&'()*+,-.?<=>@~^{|}_\\u0027 \\u005B]*")) {
            return false;
        }
```

Anyway, thanks everybody for help. Cheers